# Cannot get Android Emulator to Work on M1 Mac (RN Project)

Tags: android, android-emulator, metro-bundler

It feels like I've tried every solution on the internet, and nothing seems to work. My emulators start, but they refuse to connect to my project no matter what I do. The build works and is currently in the Google Play Store, so it WORKS on Google, it's just my M1 is not letting me test on my machine in the most infuriating of ways.
my `bash_profile` looks like this...

```
export ANDROID_HOME="$PATH:/Users/**********/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/**********/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools"
export PATH="$PATH:/ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH="$PATH:/ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH="$PATH:/ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH="$PATH:/ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

and my project's `local.properties` looks like this...

```
sdk.dir=/Users/**********/Library/Android/sdk
```

and I have Android Studio installed and set up. Whenever I run `npc react-native run-android` I get this error...

```
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
...
...
warn Failed to connect to development server using "adb reverse": spawnSync adb ENOENT
info Starting the app...
error Failed to start the app.
Error: spawnSync adb ENOENT
```

Fine, so if I try to start it via Android Studio, I get this following error...

```
Could not connect to development server.

Ensure that Metro is running
```

FINE, so let me spin up the hard downloaded Android Emulator and run it on that. I then get this error...

```
Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running Metro or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle` is packaged correctly for release
```

This is where I hit a wall, because I've never touched that file but I've gotten both this and other Android RN projects to run on my machine before. I sincerely have no idea what's going on, does anyone have a direction to point me?